# Отображение страницы с другим URL-адресом

Tags: .htaccess

Не могу реализовать редирект. Есть страница:

```
http://obruchalnye-kolca.juveros-shop.ru/jewel/obruchaljnye-koljca.html
```

Она же должна показываться с урлом: `http://obruchalnye-kolca.juveros-shop.ru`

Башку сломал уже как.

Comment: Т.е. при заходе на главную сайта должна отображаться инфа с вложеной страницы?

Comment: Не вдаваясь в подробности, да.

Answer (score 1):

http://htaccess.net.ru/doc/htaccess/directoryIndex.php

Answer (score 1):

А я поделюсь своим решением чпу:

**файл .htaccess**

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> RewriteRule (.*)$  index.php/$1 [QSA]

**файл: index.php**

> ```
> // разбираем строку запроса, и формируем массив
> $array_url = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
> foreach($array_url as $value_url)
> {
>         if(!empty($value_url)) 
>         {
>           $SEF[] = trim(urldecode($value_url));
>       }
> }
>
> // просмотр массива
> //echo '<pre>'.var_export($SEF).'</pre>';
> ```

Все просто.

Comment: 1.Уберите слеши с строки //echo '<pre>'.var_export($SEF).'</pre>';
2.Зайдите: адрес_вашего_сайта.ru/mod/news/post
3.Смотрим как красиво все получилось

Answer (score 0):

Я не буду расписывать тут "как ?" и "что ?"
Просто прочти эту статью, там все довольно просто и понятно.
[Ссылка](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=18&LESSON_ID=943)

Comment: нету там ничего такого